# Heavy GUI application with Python?

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to create high GUI apps or graphics intensive games using python? I am a beginner at programming I want to make GUI apps along with web applications and also I'm interested in Machine Learning. Many resources says python is best for ML and Web apps and not for GUI Is there any ways to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to create 2D games with Python, there are several libraries you can use:

- [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) or [PyGame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [Pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home)

I have also heard good things about [Panda3D](https://www.panda3d.org/) for 3D games. There is an openGL wrapper as well, but that one sounds like it has quite the learning curve.

Machine Learning is a different ballgame entirely. You would want to look up pandas, matplotlib, dask and several other libraries to get started with that discipline.